# OSX Homebrew and Multiple Versions of Programs VIM

Tags: macos, vim, homebrew

Vim is natively installed on MacOS. I recently installed VIM 8 using Homebrew.

Is there any way to remove the natively installed version of VIM?

Is it common practice to do so, or not?

I'm looking to keep my machine as lean as possible. Also don't see a need to have the old version of VIM around.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the bundled version of vim isn't recommended, and is in fact quite difficult:

[image]

`/usr` is protected by [System Integrity Protection](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/09/os-x-10-11-el-capitan-the-ars-technica-review/8/), which you would need to [disable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11) in order to change the contents of `/usr/bin`. Since `vim` takes up about 1 MB, this probably isn't worth it.

As long as you have `usr/local/bin` listed before `/usr/bin` in your `PATH`, you'll never open the system-supplied `vim` anyways. It's probably good practice to keep it around so that users who do not have `/usr/local/bin` in their path can still use vim (e.g. `root` for commands like `visudo` or `crontab -e`).